# Breakout game: Trouble with ball/paddle collisions and movements

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods, monogame, breakout

I'm having trouble with my method, my balls movement in breakout game and collisions between ball and paddle. 
I have a bug too, when the ball hits left or right side on paddle. The bug does so the ball goes threw paddle and speed becomes alot faster after that.

So i'm asking you for another solution on ball movement so it's more flexible and alot like the real breakout game :)

```
    void BallPaddleCollisions()
    {
        //IF BALL HITS LEFT/RIGHT SIDE
        if (ball_rect.X > Window.ClientBounds.Width - ball_texture.Width || ball_rect.X < 0)
            ball_speed.X *= -1;

        //IF BALL HITS THE ROOF
        if (ball_rect.Y > Window.ClientBounds.Height - ball_texture.Height || ball_rect.Y < 0)
            ball_speed.Y *= -1;

        //IF BALL HITS THE BOTTOM
        if (ball_rect.Y > Window.ClientBounds.Height - ball_texture.Height)
        {
            //NEW VALUES TO BALL AND PADDLE
            ball_rect.X = (Window.ClientBounds.Width - ball_texture.Width) / 2;
            ball_rect.Y = 556;
            paddle_rect.X = (Window.ClientBounds.Width - paddle_texture.Width) / 2;
            paddle_rect.Y = 580;
        }

        //IF PADDLE HITS RIGHT SIDE, STOPS
        if (paddle_rect.X > Window.ClientBounds.Width - paddle_rect.Width)
            paddle_rect.X = (Window.ClientBounds.Width - paddle_rect.Width);

        //IF PADDLE HITS LEFT SIDE, STOPS
        if (paddle_rect.X < 0)
            paddle_rect.X = 0;

        //IF BALL HIT PADDLE
        if (paddle_rect.Intersects(ball_rect))
        {
            ball_speed.Y *= -1;

            //WHEN YOU HOLD LEFT KEY
            if (holdingleft == true)
            {
                ball_speed.X -= 3;
            }
            //WHEN YOU HOLD RIGHT KEY
            else if (holdingright == true)
            {
                ball_speed.X += 3;
            }
            //IF YOU ARE NOT HOLDING ANY KEY AND STANDING STILL WITH PADDLE
            else if (resetballspeed == true)
            {
                ball_speed.X = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
        else if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        {
            Start = true;
        }

        //IF YOU HIT SPACEBAR THIS WILL START
        if (Start == true)
        {
            ball_rect.X += (int)ball_speed.X;
            ball_rect.Y += (int)ball_speed.Y;
        }
```

Comment: I think it will be better to first to *Fix my OOP in code* and then to post.. Will make it much easier to help you..

Comment: Don´t post your entire code, no one here has the time (and probably the right mood) to analyse your whole code and look for any errors or any code-smells. Only post the relevant parts that show your problem.